# Functor from category of group representations to space of $G$ invariants

Tags: category-theory, representation-theory

For a representation $(V,\rho)$ of a group $G$, define the subspace of
  $G$-invariants by
  $$
  V^G=\{v\in V: \rho(g)v=v\quad \forall g\in G\}
  $$
and want to prove the following:

- $V\mapsto V^G$ is a functor from the category of representations to the category of vector spaces over algebraically closed $k$ with characteristic $0$.
- This functor is left exact but not necessarily exact. It is exact when $G$ is finite.

So, I mean, let $Rep_G$ and $Vect_{k}$ denote representations of $G$ over $k$ and $k$ vector spaces, and $F((V,\rho))=V^G$. This map clearly maps the correct objects to the correct objects, but I'm struggling to see how $F$ acts on morphisms $T:V_1\to V_2$ with $\rho_2(g)\circ T=T\circ \rho_1(g)$. Is it really as trivial as just letting $F(T)=T$ and ignoring the extra structure? I feel like there has to be something else going on here, or else we could just map $F((V,\rho))=V$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The action on morphisms is given by restricting a morphism to invariants. There's nothing surprising going on here.

$V^G$ is representable: in fact it is represented by $k$ (the base field) with the trivial action of $G$. Hence it is not only left exact but continuous, and in fact has a left adjoint. $k$ being algebraically closed is irrelevant.

Your statement about when $V^G$ is exact requires a bit of modification. By the above observation, $V^G$ is exact iff $k$ is projective as a $k[G]$-module. This is true if $G$ is finite *and* $k$ has characteristic not dividing $|G|$, since in this case $k[G]$ is semisimple and so all $k[G]$-modules are projective.

Comment: That wasn't meant to be an iff statement, just an example of when it holds (this is a book problem I found, I just simplified it). I'm also not sure what you mean by representable.

Comment: @Moya: but even the "if" direction is wrong, in the case when $k$ has characteristic dividing $|G|$.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I think I got it and can work from here. Is there any prefered reference for this sort of thing (I found some notes you wrote, but that's mostly on Homological algebra and mentions this in the intro). This is my first run in with representation theory.

Comment: @Moya: the section on group (co)homology in any homological algebra textbook should contain a discussion of these sorts of things.