# Counterexample to exactness of functor from group representations to fixed points

Tags: representation-theory, examples-counterexamples, homological-algebra

I recently asked this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1207114/functor-from-category-of-group-representations-to-space-of-g-invariants). Now, the answer there claimed that the functor $()^G:Rep_G\to Vect_{\mathbb{C}}$, where $Rep_G$ are complex representations of a group $G$, and $V^G=\{v\in V: \rho(g)v=v\forall g\in G\}$, is left exact since it is representable as a Hom functor, so left exactness holds. This is all well and good (a bit above my level but interesting nonetheless) but this question is asking about a specific counterexample.

Let $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$ be an exact sequence, $G=\mathbb{Z}$ and let $B=\mathbb{C}^2$ with $\rho_B(n)=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & n\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$. I'm supposed to show that $B^G\to C^G\to 0$ is not exact.

So, $B^G$ is $1$ dimensional spanned by $\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 0\end{pmatrix}$, so if we suppose $S:B\to C$ in the exact sequence, and $S^G:B^G\to C^G$ in the corresponding sequence makes the sequence $0\to A^G\to B^G\to C^G\to 0$ exact. Then either $\dim C^G=0,1$, and they both reduce to the same case: either $S^G$ is an isomorphism or $T^G:A^G\to B^G$ is an isomorphism, for $T:A\to B$ in the original sequence. Now this is where I'm stuck.

Ideas?

Edit: Many proofs of this that I've seen (such as that in Rotman's Homological Algebra book) just rely on the left exactness of the hom functor, which is fine but not helpful to understanding this specific example.
Edit 2: I did prove that $0\to A^G\to B^G\to C^G$ without much difficulty by direct computation.

Comment: You need to compute $A^G$ and $C^G$, this is really simple linear algebra. Note that because $G=\mathbb{Z}$, $E^G$ is the space of eigenvectors of $\rho(1)$ corresponding to the eigenvalue 1.

Comment: Yeah, so as I said in the post, $A^G\to B^G$ is injective, so it is either the trivial map (if $A^G=0$) or an isomorphism, and $A$ has dimension $\leq 2$, but beyond this I don't see how to compute $A^G$.

Comment: What is $A$ and how $G$ acts on it ? (In fact, what are the possible values of $A$ ? I claim that there are only three of them and only one that is non trivial)

Comment: $A$ is a complex vector space, and $G$ acts on $A$ as a matrix which has at least rank $1$.

Comment: I meant, $A$ is a sub-representation of $B$ and there are only three of them, and only one that is non trivial. What are they ?

Comment: $A\subset B$ has to be a subrepresentation, but how are there only $3$ subreps? There's $B^G$, and other than that, not sure. $B$ itself, and $A$.

Comment: Well, the trivial ones are $\{0\}$ and $B$. Now, if $A$ is one dimensional, spanned by $v$, then $v$ is an eigenvector, and so $A=k.\binom{1}{0}$. In particular, $G$ acts trivially on $A$ and $A^G\rightarrow B^G$ is an isomorphism. Now compute $C$ and $C^G$ to see that the sequence is not exact.

Comment: But what if $A$ is not $1$ dimensional? What prevents $A\equiv B$

Comment: Then $A$ is $\{0\}$ or $B$. In that case the sequence will remain exact.

Comment: Nevermind. Obviously. Thank you so much for everything/putting up with me for that!

Comment: Well, because now that we have $A$, we can compute $C$ and $C^G$. Obviously $C$ is one-dimensional, now can you show that $G$ act trivially on it ?

Comment: I see. It's a counterexample to right exactness. You're right. Sorry, staying up a bit late since I couldn't figure this one out. And yes, I can see that $G$ acts trivially on $C$, so $A$ and $C$ are isomorphic.